# How to find differences between two collections

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have following DTOs:

```
@Data
public class PersonDTO implements Diffable<PersonDTO> {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<AddressDTO> addresses;

    @Override
    public DiffResult diff(PersonDTO personDTO) {
        return new DiffBuilder(this, personDTO, SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE)
                .append("id", this.id, personDTO.getId())
                .append("firstName", this.firstName, personDTO.getFirstName())
                .append("lastName", this.lastName, personDTO.getLastName())
                .append("addresses", addresses, personDTO.getAddresses())
                .build();
    }
}

@Data
public class AddressDTO implements Diffable<AddressDTO> {

    private String id;
    private String personId;
    private String addressType;
    private String street;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String postalCode;
    private String city;
    private String countryId;

    @Override
    public DiffResult diff(AddressDTO addressDTO) {
        return new DiffBuilder(this, addressDTO, SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE)
                .append("id", this.id, addressDTO.getId())
                .append("personId", this.personId, addressDTO.getPersonId())
                .append("addressType", this.addressType, addressDTO.getAddressType())
                .append("street", this.street, addressDTO.getStreet())
                .append("houseNumber", this.houseNumber, addressDTO.getHouseNumber())
                .append("postalCode", this.postalCode, addressDTO.getPostalCode())
                .append("city", this.city, addressDTO.getCity())
                .append("countryId", this.countryId, addressDTO.getCountryId())
                .build();
    }
}
```

My main goal is to find differences between two similar person objects. Currently I've tried to use `Diffable` interface from apache commons which is perfectly good for object. Please advise how to deal with collections when size of each collection can be different. For instance few addresses were removed, few was added and few was updated. Please see example below:

[image]

Probably there is another library which helps to achieve similar goals, please advice

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "Please advice how to deal with collections when size of each can be difference."

Comment: @rootExplorr there was typo, I've just fixed this, please let me know if it is still unclear.

Answer (score -1):

source can be your first object

target can be your second object

```
Iterator targetIt = target.iterator();
for (Object obj:source)
  if (!obj.equals(targetIt.next())
    // Element has changed
```